# Tangential gradient only depends on values of $u$ on $M$ - Proof explanation

Tags: vector-analysis

For a $C^1$-function $u$ defined on a two-dimensional hypersurface $M$ we can define the tangential gradient as $$\nabla_Mu=\nabla \tilde{u}-(\nabla\tilde{u}\cdot n)n$$ where $\nabla$ denotes the usual Euclidean gradient, $n$ being the unit normal and $\tilde{u}$ being a smooth extension of $u$ to a neighborhood of $M$.

Now there is a Lemma that the tangential gradient only depends on values of $\tilde{u}$ on $M$. The proofs I have seen start like this:
"It suffices to show that $u=0$ on $M$ implies $\nabla_M u=0$."

Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma is likely “the tangential gradient only depends on values of $\tilde u$ on $M$”. ($u$ is defined only on $M$.)

The proof comes the linearity of the formula:

$$
\nabla_M (u_1+u_2) = \nabla(\tilde u_1+\tilde u_2) + (n\cdot\nabla(\tilde u_1+\tilde u_2))n=\nabla\tilde u_1 + (n\cdot\tilde u_1)n + \nabla\tilde u_2 + (n\cdot\tilde u_2)n = 
\nabla_M u_1 + \nabla_M u_2
$$

So if you have proved that $u=0 \Rightarrow \nabla_Mu=0$, then every smooth extension will give you the same result (since their difference is smooth and equals zero on $M$).

Comment: Thanks. I think it is something really simple I'm missing here. Where did we get that the difference of $\tilde{u}$ and $u$ must be zero?

Comment: Let's say we have 2 different smooth extensions for $u$: $\tilde u_1$ and  $\tilde u_2$. Their difference  $\tilde u_1- \tilde u_2$ is a smooth extension of a function $v=0$ on M.